# How to extract different divs between two anchor tags in htmlagility?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

```
<html>
<A NAME="doc_id_1"></A>

<div class="find1">
Iam here, extract me.
</div>
<div class = "find2">

iam here also, extract me as well.
</div>

<A NAME="doc_id_2"></A>

</html>
```

I have used below code to extract data :

```
    var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@name = 'doc_id_1']");
    var nodes1 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@name = 'doc_id_2']");

    foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
    {
        string yourText1 = node.InnerText;
        //var yourText2 = node.NextSibling.SelectNodes("//div");
        string yourText2 = node.NextSibling.InnerHtml;

        //foreach (HtmlNode var in yourText2)
        //{
        //    string yourText3 = var.InnerHtml;
        //}

    }
```

I don't want to give class name on those div. Because i am writing a generic code.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option, using Linq:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html: Resources.Html);

var startNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[@name = 'doc_id_1']");
var endNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[@name = 'doc_id_2']");

var parent = startNode.ParentNode;

var nodesYouWant = parent.ChildNodes
    .SkipWhile(node => node != startNode)   // skip all nodes up to the start node
    .Skip(1)                                // skip the start node
    .TakeWhile(node => node != endNode)     // take all nodes up to the next anchor
    .Where(node => node.Name == "div");     // select only div nodes
```

Or:

```
var currentNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[@name = 'doc_id_1']");
var endNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[@name = 'doc_id_2']");

var nodesYouWant = GetEnclosedNodes(currentNode, endNode).Where(node => node.Name == "div");

private static IEnumerable<HtmlNode> GetEnclosedNodes(HtmlNode currentNode, HtmlNode endNode)
{
    currentNode = currentNode.NextSibling;

    while (currentNode != null && currentNode != endNode)
    {
        yield return currentNode;

        currentNode = currentNode.NextSibling;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you will know the name value of the two anchor tags.

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();

var firstAnchor = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[@name = 'doc_id_1']");

var div = firstAnchor.NextSibling;

while (div.Name != "doc_id_2") //when the name of the second anchor is found we have no more divs
{
    var divText = div.InnerText; //do whatever with this
    div = div.NextSibling;
}
```